How to identify a row based on another row?
I got stuck on this column creation for a while. Really hope someone could help me out here. I even start to doubt if what I want to achieve is doable in power bi or not....
What I want to achieve:

If it's a duplicate in column "key", the column "Quantity" has a positive value that has an offset negative value in another row, and the Plant codes are different. Then mark the negative quantity row "delete". Like the last two rows, I want to keep the last second one and delete the last one. So these two records indicate the same transaction. One receiving and one supplying. I only want to keep one.
If the movement type "351" is a duplicate in column “key”, the plant codes are the same, then mark "delete" to the row that has a Posting Date that’s no later than the one in the row with movement type “352” . So movement 352 has a corresponding movement 351, which needs to be identified.
It can be in two columns since these are two different requests there.

Sample table:
Plant   Material        Movement Type   Purchase Order  Item     Key                        Posting Date   Quantity 
6417    0-810-030-805   351             4000121095      70       0-810-030-805400012109570  3/13/2024      8.00 
6417    0-810-030-805   352             4000121095      70       0-810-030-805400012109570  3/13/2024      -1.00    
6417    0-810-030-805   351             4000121095      70       0-810-030-805400012109570  8/8/2023       3.00 
6417    0-810-034-517   351             4000121095      90       0-810-034-517400012109590  8/7/2023       1.00 
6602    0-810-015-654   351             4000121902      10       0-810-015-654400012190210  9/5/2023       2.00 
6602    0-810-015-654   351             4000121902      10       0-810-015-654400012190210  11/8/2023      3.00 
6602    0-810-015-619   351             4000121902      10       0-810-015-619400012190210  10/3/2023      2.00 
6602    0-810-018-910   351             4000121902      210      0-810-018-9104000121902210 10/18/2023     4.00 
6602    0-810-020-807   351             4000121902      220      0-810-020-8074000121902220 10/18/2023     3.00 
6602    0-810-018-908   351             4000121902      230      0-810-018-9084000121902230 10/18/2023     12.00    
6602    0-810-018-908   352             4000121902      230      0-810-018-9084000121902230 10/19/2023     -6.00    
6602    0-810-018-908   351             4000121902      230      0-810-018-9084000121902230 11/2/2023      6.00 
6482    0-810-037-471   351             4000122926      10       0-810-037-471400012292610  10/9/2023      1.00 
6509    0-810-037-471   351             4000122926      10       0-810-037-471400012292610  10/9/2023      -1.00    

What I want to achieve:
Plant   Material        Movement Type   Purchase Order  Item    Key                         Posting Date    Quantity  Target Column 1   Target Column 2
6417    0-810-030-805   351             4000121095      70      0-810-030-805400012109570   3/13/2024       8.00                        Delete  
6417    0-810-030-805   352             4000121095      70      0-810-030-805400012109570   3/13/2024       -1.00                       Keep    
6417    0-810-030-805   351             4000121095      70      0-810-030-805400012109570   8/8/2023        3.00                        Keep    
6417    0-810-034-517   351             4000121095      90      0-810-034-517400012109590   8/7/2023        1.00                        Keep    
6602    0-810-015-654   351             4000121902      10      0-810-015-654400012190210   9/5/2023        2.00                        Keep    
6602    0-810-015-654   351             4000121902      10      0-810-015-654400012190210   11/8/2023       3.00                        Keep    
6602    0-810-015-619   351             4000121902      10      0-810-015-619400012190210   10/3/2023       2.00                        Keep    
6602    0-810-018-910   351             4000121902      210     0-810-018-9104000121902210  10/18/2023      4.00                        Keep    
6602    0-810-020-807   351             4000121902      220     0-810-020-8074000121902220  10/18/2023      3.00                        Keep    
6602    0-810-018-908   351             4000121902      230     0-810-018-9084000121902230  10/18/2023      12.00                       Delete  
6602    0-810-018-908   352             4000121902      230     0-810-018-9084000121902230  10/19/2023      -6.00                       Keep    
6602    0-810-018-908   351             4000121902      230     0-810-018-9084000121902230  11/2/2023       6.00                        Keep    
6482    0-810-037-471   351             4000122926      10      0-810-037-471400012292610   10/9/2023       1.00      Keep              
6509    0-810-037-471   351             4000122926      10      0-810-037-471400012292610   10/9/2023       -1.00     Delete            

Have been stuck here for 2 days now. Any help will be appreciated!

Wy do have empty values for the Target Column 1 ?

you can try this to create two columns
Column =
VAR _check =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[PurchaseOrder] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[PurchaseOrder] )
                && 'Table'[Plant] <> EARLIER ( 'Table'[Plant] )
                && 'Table'[Quantity]
                    = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Quantity] ) * -1
        ),
        'Table'[Plant]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( _check ) || 'Table'[Quantity] >= 0, BLANK (), "delete" )



Column2=
VAR _date =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[PurchaseOrder] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[PurchaseOrder] )
                && 'Table'[Plant] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Plant] )
                && 'Table'[MovementType] = 352
                && 'Table'[Material] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Material] )
        ),
        'Table'[PostingDate]
    )
VAR _date2 =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[PurchaseOrder] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[PurchaseOrder] )
                && 'Table'[Plant] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Plant] )
                && 'Table'[MovementType] = 351
                && 'Table'[PostingDate] <= _date
                && 'Table'[Material] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Material] )
        ),
        'Table'[PostingDate]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( 'Table'[MovementType] = 351 && 'Table'[PostingDate] = _date2, "delete" )


